# The user specified as a definer ('user'@'localhost') does not exist

Tags: c#, mysql

As per my application requirement, I have renamed user by

```
String.Format("RENAME USER '{0}'@'%' TO '{1}'@'%';", OldUsername, NewUsername)
```

It renamed properly in database. But when I execute next command with renamed(new) user name, it threw error with 1449.

> The user specified as a definer ('OldUser'@'localhost') does not exist

I have change connection string also.
Please suggest me what I am missing here.

Comment: Have you flushed the permissions?

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by flushed? @RowlandShaw

Comment: See also: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privilege-changes.html

Comment: Sounds like you may need to redefine your stored programs (sprocs/triggers/etc).

Comment: @eggyal Yeah, I have redefine my definer with new (renamed) username and it is working fine now.